# DocuSign and Powershell - bulk create templates

Tags: docusignapi

I am looking for someone that could assist me with a Powershell script / steps on how I can bulk create 60 templates in DocuSign.

They all contain the same fields, number of pages, recipients however the title changes and data inside the additional pages past the signature fields.

Is there a way to use import-CSV to pull the title and file path of each document and then create a template for each one please.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/create-template/

I have come across thus but would appreciate it if someone could assist me with it.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here are the current Powershell examples offered by docusign: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-powershell
You can find here how to create a template with a powershell example: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/create-template/

If you want further assistance you can always reach out to DocuSign's support by opening a ticket here:
https://support.docusign.com/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the information however I reached out to DocuSign and the response I got was to ask 'Powershell' then i posted on their forum and told to reach out on here for support.

Comment: I believe i have found most of the script HOWEVER I need to add the following: Text boxes, Signature fields, Full Name Tabs but i am unsure as to what these would be called when using a Powershell script if anyone know